# What is the difference between time of AES in Python and in C?

Tags: aes

Can someone tell me how fast AES encrypt in C or C++? I found the AES code in Python:

https://gist.github.com/jeetsukumaran/1291836

and I measured how fast it encrypts. But I can't run the AES code in C. I don't know C and the codes I found don't work on an online interpreter. Maybe someone has a working, clean code and could compare it?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use your system-provided AES instead? That will be faster because it should use your CPU's built-in support for AES, if present (most modern Intel chips have hardware-accelerated AES).

Comment: I want to study the working time of pure AES to compare it, also with my own algorithm. There cannot be any hardware-acceleration.

Comment: There is no such thing as “Pure AES” - any algorithm as complex as AES can be written in many different ways and styles with their own runtime (space, time) characteristics and platform-dependent optimisations. You cannot say “there cannot be any hardware acceleration” because even without using hardware-AES you still benefit from other hardware features that aren’t specific to AES (such as AVX, SSE, etc).

Comment: To that-end, I wouldn’t be surprised if a modern compiler could take a basic AES program and generate AVX-aware machine-code that’s so optimised it’s actually faster than hardware-AES...

Comment: So let's assume I'm creating a program or application using AES. How do you decide which language you should choose if you want fastest speed? You can compare speed of languages, but different languages gives different speeds at different instructions. Isn't it the best to compare the code in one language and another? Let's say I'm just wondering - should I use Python or C in my project. Of course - theoretically C will be better (faster). But let's say I would like to know how many times better exactly. Then we have to estimate it somehow - maybe that way?

Comment: "How do you decide which language you should choose if you want fastest speed?" - **you don't** - that decision shouldn't be made at all. If you want fast AES then use hardware-AES, after that if you want anything else done fast then write it in assembly, but implementing AES in assembly code would be the absolute worst possible thing to do because one mistake could easily blow your entire AES encryption - and it's very easy to make mistakes when writing assembly code.

Comment: "Isn't it the best to compare the code in one language and another?" - no, such comparisons are meaningless. As I said above, a great compiler for any language can turn awful-looking (but not necessarily awfully written!) code into amazing machine-code, and a bad compiler will turn the best written-for-performance code into something unnecessarily slow.